# varnish and dynamic content from API

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, varnish

I have a vue app served with Laravel API, so we hope 30.000 people at least, the application present an static data for everyone, but there is some data according to users prefers, so I have the idea to use some cache system like varnish, my question is, if the content is dynamically and some data change according on user, it is good to use the cache system or not? And how can I do to caching only some data and leave other out of the cache system?

Comment: Anything requested via ajax by the vue components will never be cached.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the response, this what you said is by default or should i config something?